# Term for talking about a subject or idea you did not want to talk about?

Tags: single-word-requests

Specifically, is there a term for the situation where both parties agree not to discuss a certain subject and in so doing end up engaging in a discussion about the very topic they said they wouldn't?

An example:

> Person A: "What do you want to talk about?"
>
> Person B: "Anything but the weather."
>
> Person A: "Agreed, I find it boring to discuss the weather."
>
> Person B: "Me too. Oh, that reminds me -- did you hear it was supposed to snow tomorrow?"
>
> Person A: "Wow, really? I didn't know that. So long as it doesn't rain!"
>
> Person B: "You do realize we now actually *are* talking about the weather, right?"

Comment: You might consider a metaphor like:  They've *wandered into forbidden territory*

Answer (score 2):

Consider **[elephant in the room](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elephant?q=elephant%20in%20the%20room#elephant__8)**

> a major problem or controversial issue which is obviously present but is avoided as a subject for discussion:
>   *they’ve steadfastly ignored the elephant in the room: the ever-growing debt burden on graduates*

In a sense, it's a form of **[litotes](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/litotes?q=litotes)**

> ironical understatement in which an affirmative is expressed by the negative of its contrary (e.g. I shan’t be sorry for I shall be glad)

The very process of avoidance results in the consideration of the avoided concept.

Comment: I think OP is looking for a term for actually talking about the elephant in the room

Comment: @Jim Sounds like *I come to bury Caesar ...*

Comment: My favorite example of a litotes is: "He's a man of no small means."